# Problema con string en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy practicando con C++, uso visual code y cuando hago los string de la siguiente forma
Ej:

char nombre[20];

ejecuto el programa y abre la consola sin ningun problema... pero si cambio a string...

Ej:

string nombre;

no abre la consola... parece que va a ejecutar pero no abre.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    string Nombre = "Carlos";
    cout<<Nombre<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

esa simpleza no la ejecuta... pero repito, si vuelvo todo a char[] si ejecuta. Que puede ser?

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: El programa es completamente correcto y funciona con normalidad. Si falla debe ser algo no relacionado con el código.

Comment: Ese es todo el codigo... simple, resumido y falla... por eso sospecho que puede ser configuracion de algo como la extension. pro no encuento info sobre una posible falla con los string o si es que hay que configurar algo mas para usarlos

Comment: o sea.... si lo uso asi funciona y corre bien:                       
                                                                                           
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){

        char Nombre[10] = "Hola";

        cout << Nombre <<endl;

        system("pause");


    }

Comment: La prueba de que el código que expones funciona correctamente: [link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ojfv0773drcbECYz)